# When we manually switch off the permissions from the settings and go back to our app ,its crashes with null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio

Our app was working on target SDK version 22 but due to Google policies we have updated it to version 26 recently , whenever we manually switch off the permission and switch on it at same moment, it crashes with null pointer exception at many places, please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Apply try n catch to the code you are using permission or in log cat try to find which line crash is coming. Apply try catch to that code also and handle your way.